# Audio is not there in the video generated with Editly

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have been trying to generate a video from Editly.
There is a video layer, some text and then I am trying to include audio layer as well.
Video is gettig generated but audio is not there in the video.
Below is the spec looks like

```js
const editlySpec = {
    width: 1080,
    height: 1920,
    outPath: "./output-video.mp4",
    clips: [
        {
            duration: 4, // Set the duration of your clip in seconds
            layers: [
                {
                    type: "video",
                    path: "./exam-preparation-video-1.mp4", // Replace with the path to your video file
                },
                {
                    type: "title",
                    text: "Your Text Here", // Replace with your desired text
                    position: "center",
                    scale: 1.0,
                },
                {
                    type: "audio",
                    path: "./sample-audio-4-sec.mp3", // Replace with the path to your audio file
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't delve too much into the specifics, but I believe the answer to your issue lies in using the type deatached-audio rather than audio. My hunch is that it has something to do with the audio linked to the video. Given the presumption that your video lacks in audio, you could try this modification.

Try to change:

```js
{
  type: "audio",
  path: "./sample-audio-4-sec.mp3"file
}
```

To

```js
{
  type: "deatached-audio",
  path: "./sample-audio-4-sec.mp3"file
}
```